# What is the meaning of "nimbus"? Is it a verb, noun or an adjective?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

From *The Shining*, by Stephen King:

> Across from them—who knew how far?—an even taller mountain reared into the sky, its jagged tip only a silhouette that was now nimbused by the sun, which was beginning its decline

What is the meaning and part of speech of *nimbused*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

King derives this verb from the noun **nimbus**, which describes a *circle of light*, not unlike a *halo*.

Imagine how the sun sets behind the mountain and how the dark silhouette of its tip is outlined by the bright and radiant light of the sun behind it.

Stephen King uses the verb in this sentence to express how it is the sun that is creating a nimbus around the tip of the mountain.